# What defines a "low" predictive error

Tags: bias, approximate-bayesian-computation

Using an Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC) approach I have estimated a parameter from my observed data.

Now, following this vignette from the R package abc (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/abc/vignettes/abcvignette.pdf page 4) I am estimating the predictive error (PE) of my estimate:

[image]

I have two questions:

1) What does Var(theta(i)) mean? How can I get a variance for one value?
2) I think the PE is unbounded? I would only want a low value? How low should I expect this value to be?

Comment: $\text{Var}(\theta_i)$ is constant over $i$

Comment: @Xi'an thanks. would you mind elaborate on that? I don't have a strong maths background